# Problema al importar SweetAlert Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sweetalert

Intento implementar SweetAlert a mi código

```
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.2'
```

pero al momento de sincronizar me arroja el siguiente error:

```
INFO: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been 
replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.

It will be removed at the end of 2019.

For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration- 
avoidance.

To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use - 
Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more 
information.

Affected Modules: app
```

Estoy usando compileSdkVersion 29. ¿Alguien podría decirme como solucionar esto por favor?

Comment: tenes desactualizada la version de la libreria. Cambia el 1.5.2 por 1.6.2

Comment: Eso era, muchas gracias.